# Train function hangs using R-caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Hwæt,

Attempting to make a random forest with caret, my training command causes the process to hang for at least 24 hours (after which I shut it down).  The idea is to correlate land cover data with local temperatures, so I have a set of excel files containing sensor readings and a csv describing land cover at each location.  This is just a dry run to make sure all of the moving parts work, so the dataset is laughably small: only half a dozen locations with unchanging land cover conditions.  This may be the source of the problem, as it began after I wrote the following code to create my datasets:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(RStoolbox)
library(ggplot2)
library(doParallel)
library(caTools)
library(gdata)

# Get land cover data
sensor_environment_folder <- "C://etc"
land_cover <- read.csv(paste0(sensor_environment_folder, "Logger_Simplified.csv"))

# Get the list of sensor logs and split it into two lists of files
sensor_reading_folder <- "C://etc2"
files <- list.files(sensor_reading_folder)
split <- sample.split(files, SplitRatio= 4/5, group=NULL)
training_files <- files[split]
testing_files <- files[!split]

# Load raw data

for(file in training_files) {
  if(!exists("training_raw")) {
    training_raw <- read.xlsx(paste0(sensor_reading_folder,file), colNames=TRUE)
  } else {
    temp_data <- read.xlsx(paste0(sensor_reading_folder,file), colNames=TRUE)
    training_raw <- rbind(training_raw,temp_data)
    rm(temp_data)
  }
}

for(file in testing_files) {
  if(!exists("testing_raw")) {
    testing_raw <- read.xlsx(paste0(sensor_reading_folder,file), colNames=TRUE)
  } else {
    temp_data <- read.xlsx(paste0(sensor_reading_folder,file), colNames=TRUE)
    testing_raw <- rbind(testing_raw, temp_data)
    rm(temp_data)
  }
}
```

Data prep involves joining the temperature readings to the land cover data, based on common UtilID (the name of the sensor) and XY coords, data which I then discard:

```
# Prepare the data

model_vars<-c("Point_X", "Point_Y", "UtilID", "DateTime", "TempF")
training_merge <- merge(training_raw[model_vars],land_cover)
training_data <- subset(
              training_merge[complete.cases(training_merge),],
              select=c(TempF,DateTime, S_10000Pct.N.19.11, S_2000Pct.N.19.11))
testing_merge <- merge(testing_raw[model_vars],land_cover)
testing_data <- subset(
              testing_merge[complete.cases(testing_merge),],
              select=c(TempF,DateTime, S_10000Pct.N.19.11, S_2000Pct.N.19.11))

rm(training_merge, testing_merge)
```

All of this runs fine so far, and the dataset looks like I expect it to:

```
>str(training_data)
'data.frame':   431663 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ TempF             : num  52.9 52.8 52.5 52.7 52.6 ...
 $ DateTime          : num  43387 43387 43387 43387 43387 ...
 $ S_10000Pct.N.19.11: num  18.7 18.7 18.7 18.7 18.7 ...
 $ S_2000Pct.N.19.11 : num  16 16 16 16 16 ...
```

But when it proceeds to the train function, it issues the message "" and hangs:

```
# Train the algorithm

myControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                          number=2,
                          repeats=2,
                          returnResamp='all',
                          allowParallel=TRUE)

mc <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel

set.seed(1999)

learner <- train(TempF ~ DateTime + S_10000Pct.N.19.11 + S_2000Pct.N.19.11,
                  data=training_data,
                  method="rf",
                  metric="Rsquared",
                  preProc=c("center","scale"),
                  trControl=myControl,
                  verbose = TRUE)

stopCluster(mc)
```

Some possible root causes which have occurred to me:

- Because there's so little data, the algorithm keeps searching indefinitely for a way to make accurate predictions (poor little thing).  It would be nice to be able to tell it to be completely blase about such things.
- There are problems with names of training variables? (I'm new to R syntax, and putting periods in the middle of names feels truly scandalous)
- Something weird in the dataset itself would not surprise me; I've had a few issues with it so far, which I've responded to by culling the most obvious culprits.

Have compared this to similar complaints, but the [most similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857772/caret-train-rf-model-inexplicably-long-execution) report seems to have been due to a lack of certain code, which I have.

Comment: The training data frame size is HUGE.. This is why the algorithm hangs.. Take a random sample to reduce the dimensionality to say a thousand rows. Then split it into 70 percent training and 30 percent testing set. And then apply a classifier.

Comment: instead of using `method = "rf"`, use `method = "ranger"` to use the ranger package. This runs the randomforest algorithm in parallel automatically, aka no need for doParallel, and is way faster than using the randomForest package. With ranger the 400k+ rows shouldn't be an issue.